# What information is available to an app from the magnetometer?

Tags: hardware, sensors, magnetometer

I would like to know what other functionality is provided by the magnetometer inside android devices besides allowing applications to display a compass. Can an app do anything else with it besides display compass functionality?

Comment: Programming related questions are off-topic as per FAQ

Comment: This question is not about programming. It's about what programmers can achieve, that is, about what the device can do.

Comment: Edited and reopened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnetometer reports the magnetic strengths on the three axes of the phone. Can work as compass , metal detector and can also be used to increase mapping accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetometer measures magnetic field, so it can do anything a magnetometer can do. Other than compass, the magnetometer can be used as a metal detector for instance.